# Stream to file system from AWS Lambda NodeJs application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function (NodeJS) that builds a huge data structure.

Getting the data structure built eats up about 2 GB of memory.

Lastly, I want to push the data to S3 as a file/object.

The simple thing to do is convert the structure to a giant string, write to to /tmp, and then push to S3, but that approach kills the 3GB memory limit.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to write to /tmp line by line, so that it doesn't blow out the remainder of my memory.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use streaming to send data to S3 directly, while its being created. If you post an example code I can try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda /tmp actually only has [512 MB of space](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), and is a separate limitation from the function's memory.

You are likely hitting the 3 GB limit because you convert the structure to a string in memory, which means you have the 2 GB original data, and then 2 GB of the string conversion (well, 1 GB and then an error)

You mentioned that you have:

> an AWS Lambda function (NodeJS) that builds a huge data structure.

However, typically when working with large data the approach is to split the workload between multiple Lambdas, never loading it into a single Lambda as it goes against the design of Lambdas (the memory limits are a clear indication).

So if possible, I would recommend splitting the workload between multiple Lambdas, but if that's not possible in your use case then you can look into [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?hp=tile&so-exp=below) or the easier to work with [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/), in which case you won't run into any of the limitations you have with Lambda.